# Failed to start monitoring 0123456789ABCDEF

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

When I connect Android device to Eclipse for debugging, it will show `Failed to start monitoring 0123456789ABCDEF`, but not always. Sometimes it works perfectly. USB debugging is active, but still shows like this.

Why is it so? Can anyone help me?

Comment: If this is a development related question, you may have to ask in StackOverflow.com. You may still post it here if you rephrase your question. Any way, have you tried "adb devices" whenever you receive such messages from Eclipse? Does that show your connected device or something else?

Comment: A bit of additional information might be helpful in determining the best audience for this question. As Narayanan pointed out, checking `adb devices` from a command line would help to narrow down if this is an issue with the adb driver/communication in general (which we might be able to help you with) or if it's an Eclipse problem (which would probably get better answers on [SO]).